# What exactly is the extension of an individual variable in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

My question pertains to the semantics of classical predicate logic. If I'm working with a model M = $\langle D, v \rangle$ in which D is a non-empty set consisting of all existing obejects and $v$ is an assignment-function. The assignment-function is then determined by the condition:

(i) $v$: $\mathcal{C} \cup \mathcal{V} \rightarrow D$

$\mathcal{C}$ represents the set of all individual constants and $\mathcal{V}$ the set of all individual variables. As I understand this condition, the assignment function maps every constant and every variable onto an object in the domain. I can see, for example, that an individual constant 'a' gets mapped onto the individual 'John' in our domain. However, what does it mean to say that an individual variable 'x' gets mapped onto the domain? Isn't a variable undefined? I don't understand what exactly is assigned to it in the domain. Does an assignment function randomly map the 'x' onto an object in the domain?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A valuation maps a set of variables to elements in the domain, precisely to give meaning to formulas with free variables. So you have a formula $\varphi(x)$, which may be true for certain assignments of $x$ and false for other assignments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I understand now. There was some misunderstanding on my part on what sort of thing an individual variable exactly is and what it is that an assignment function or valuation does. It is kind of strange, because what you said isn't anything I haven't read but it did suddenly click and it did the trick. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, certain things make sense when you have a certain mindset, and the books are written by people who think like mathematicians, but it will come with time.

Comment: A free *variable* acts as a "pronoun" of natural language; a formula with a free var is like the sentence "it is red". What refers to "it" ? it depends on the context. A *variable assignment* is a way to give a reference (or denotation) to free vars.